# 'View' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-cardview, helper

I am implementing recycler view for my Xamarin android application and here is my recyclerviewadapter.cs
code, but it is showing error on view when I pass it as parameter in constructor

```
namespace FinalProject_PU.Helper
{
    class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageview { get; set; }
        //
        // public TextView Description { get; set; }
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            imageview = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            // Description = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        }
    }
    class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Data> lstData)
        {
            this.lstData = lstData;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return lstData.Count;
            }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            viewHolder.imageview.SetImageResource(lstData[position].imageid);
            //viewHolder.Description.Text = lstData[position].description;

        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.items, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here gives me 2 errors:
'View' is a namespace but is used like a type on this line

```
public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
```

and "The type or namespace name 'Data' couldn't be found(you are missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?) on this line

```
 private List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();
```

i have tried;

1. deleting the bin and obj and building the solution again
2. closing and restarting the visual studio

Comment: What namesapce is Data in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for the View error`Android.Views.View` it runs

Answer (score 0):

You have namespace issues. You will either have to try and sort them out either by

1. Removing using directives
2. Use a *static using directive*,
3. Use the fully qualified names

**Example**

This assumes you want to use the case class library `View`

```
public RecyclerViewHolder(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.View itemView) : base(itemView)
```

As for `Data`, determine where it declared, and make sure you you have a *using directive* for that namespace

---

**Additional Resources**

[using directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

[using static directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Data' is used in another .cs file check if it is then in Data class add this line in libraries: `using FinalProjectPU.` after . put your folder name where you have made Data.cs file.